# how to match answers of questions stored in differnet lists in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a external file where I stored all the questions. There is another file where I stored answers. I have converted the questions.txt file in to list. same thing I will do for answers.txt. I want to show random questions to user and then match the answer of that question. I also want to display what was the correct answer. I also want to prevent duplication of questions. There will be no options for the user. user have to give answer to his own.
Here is my code.

```
import random
def python():
   txt_file = open("python_mcqs.txt", "r")
   file_content = txt_file.read()
   #print("The file content are: ", file_content)

   content_list = file_content.split(",")
   txt_file.close()
   #print("The list is: ", content_list)
   question = []
   for x in content_list:
      question.append(x.replace("\n", ","))  
   #print(list(question))
   i= 1
   while i<=10:
      
      question_display = random.choice(question).rstrip()
      user_answer = input(question_display)
      if user_answer.lower() == "yes": # it is just a testing condition. yes will replace answers
         pass
      else:
         pass
   
      i = i + 1   
      
python()
```

**Note:** I am a beginner programmer. Please suggest me with simple code so that I can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest way to go this would be to randomise the list of questions so that they're in a random order, and then you can just go through them one after another without having to pick a random one each time, which obviously could cause duplication

python's random library already has a function for this:

```
random.shuffle(question_list)
```

will randomly shuffle the list of questions for you (it doesn't return anything, it shuffles the list in-place)

Next, you'll need a way to add answers to your questions, this would be easiest to do by adding them into the same text file. In python, when you open a file, you can put it in a for loop to have it go through each line one-by-one

```
question_list = []
txt_file = open("python_mcqs.txt", "r")
for line in txt_file:
  question_list.append(line.split(", "))
```

With that code, you can store the questions in the text file like this

> question 1, answer 1

> question 2, answer 2

and they will be automatically converted into:

```
["question 1", "answer 1"], ["question 2", "answer 2"]
```

And so when you go through each question in the array you can simply do:

```
question_display = question[0]
answer = question[1]
```

to get the question and the answer